# C makefile to compile OpenGL project directly on iphone

Tags: c, iphone, opengl, makefile

Please direct me if this question has already been asked; I did a search on the topic unable to find yet.

I am having trouble putting together a makefile that will take one or more .c OpenGL project files, uses apple-arm-darwin9 and OpenGL framework to compile into object directly on the iphone (using bash). For some reason whatever combination of framework or LIBPATH I use I am constantly seeing exceptions thrown - if anyone can point me to the right direction I'd be well on my way. Thanks

Comment: When you say 'direct to iPhone', what do you mean?  Why wouldn't you store the files on the host first, and then cross-load?

Comment: tx for responding - the .c file that has ref to GLUT.h is on the iphone itself, & i have a terminal into an iphone openssh session. I have some limitations on compiling on host machine atm.

Answer (score 1):

Too generic, and two different issues.

One, the problem of finding a command (or series of commands) that does correctly compile your code.

Two, writing a Makefile to do the job.

I'd help you with the latter, but you have to figure out the former first (which has nothing to do with Makefiles at all)...